# なんで32bitはx86?

Tags: macos

32bit版のインストーラーなどのファイル名には`x86`という文字がついていますが、これはなんなんですか?

64bit版は`x64`なのに・・・

Comment: 時代を感じますなぁ。僕が最初に触ったCPUは8080でした...。

Answer (score 11):

x86とはインストールするプログラムが使用している命令セットの通称です。

x86命令セットは正式にはIA-32という名前で、x86の名はIntelの8086および後継の80186、80286、80386、80486という「80x86」と総称されるCPUで採用されたことに由来しています。

Answer (score 11):

i8086の流れを汲むIntelのCPUは、i8086, i80186, i80386 (通称 "386"), i486 のように末尾に "86" が付けられていたため、慣例的に "x86" アーキテクチャと呼ばれています。

ただし、最近では、32ビットアーキテクチャのみを指して "x86" と記載することが一般的です。(x64のCPUも32ビットアーキテクチャと互換性があり広義には "x86" に含まれます。)